How can I make React switch routes on button click with condition?
I have a react login form with two text fields: username and password. I want the handler to check if both username and password are 'elev'. If they are, the handler should change the route and open another page. But, the handler won't change its route, and instead just refreshes the page. My current code is below. Is there anyone who can help?
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Paper, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import LoginIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Login";
import { deepPurple, purple } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [nume, setNume] = useState("");
  const [parola, setParola] = useState("");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (nume === "elev" && parola === "elev") {
      let path = "/Books";
      navigate(path);
    } else {
      setClicked(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      sx={{
        width: "450px",
        minHeight: "280px",
        margin: "50px auto",
      }}
    >
      <Paper
        elevation={4}
        sx={{
          width: "450px",
          minHeight: "280px",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          padding: 1,
          bgcolor: deepPurple[50],
          opacity: 0.9,
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h4" color={purple[800]}>
          Autentificare
          <LoginIcon fontSize="medium" />
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          required
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
          label="Nume utilizator:"
          name="nume"
          value={nume}
          error={clicked && nume !== "elev"}
          helperText={clicked && nume !== "elev" && "Nume sau parola incorecte"}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setNume(e.target.value);
            setClicked(false);
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          type="password"
          fullWidth
          label="Parola"
          variant="outlined"
          name="parola"
          value={parola}
          error={clicked && parola !== "elev"}
          helperText={clicked && parola !== "elev" && "Nume sau parola incorecte"}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setParola(e.target.value);
            setClicked(false);
          }}
        />
        <Button fullWidth type="submit" variant="contained" sx={{ bgcolor: purple[800] }}>
          Autentificare
        </Button>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;


It's hard to reproduce or identify the problem among that mui-specific code. It would be helpful if you share as well the routes definition in your application. Even better if you provide a reproducible example using some platform like stackblitz or similar.
